# Организация меток в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем добрый вечер.
У меня возникла проблема с организацией, то есть кластеризацией меток. Мне необходимо, чтобы на карте был вид страны, там было отмечено 10 городов, потом он должен разбиваться на несколько районов, а каждый район должен разбиваться на несколько участков, а участки уже на метки на карте. Вопрос такой, как мне организовать все это, чтобы можно было отследить несколько уровней кластеризации.

Я сперва попробовал сделать все через objectManager, но не получилось, так как некоторые марки не кластеризировались, а были рядом, и я не мог поделить кластеризацию на несколько уровней, так как мне необходимо показывать данные об участках, районах и городе. Данные я получаю по API в json.

Прошу дать мне совет, как мне это делать? Может быть лучше просто брать и кластеризировать все по порядку. 10 меток в участок, 5 участков в район, а их уже в полноценный город, просто если все данные запихнуть в objectMAnager, получается хаос, который я не могу контролировать.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать всё через ROM https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/ если вы готовы чтобы у вас была серверная часть

Comment: В каком плане серверная часть? Использовать правильные форматы описания объектов? Я не вижу в этом большой проблемы. Единственная проблема, это поймать и унифицировать кластеры по уровням в зависимости от zoom. Грубо говоря. Я наживаю на кластер, где 100 объектов, потом увеличивается на город, и выдается инфа о городе, участок, инфа об участке и тд. Меня это беспокоит. Спасибо большое. Пока изучу ROM.

Comment: Вот ещё примерчик вдогонку https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/tree/master/remote-object-manager-server